# sound capture using c# issue

Tags: c#, audio, capture, naudio

I have developed a sound capturing winform application using NAudio 1.3
 on c#. The idea is to capture streaming songs through sound card. It is
working perfectly fine on windows xp.
But On vista and windows7 machine if there is no sound driver installed  it also take mic voice with it
which is a big issue(i have checked it on dell laptop and if i mute the microphone than it does not capture any sound
 )i just want  to capture streaming song sound .NAudio 1.3 uses WASAPI audio capture for windows vista and 7.I need to solve this
issue urgently.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an NAudio issue, it's to do with your sound card & drivers on windows Vista and Windows 7.

On your XP machine you would be using a mixer device provided by your sound card to record the audio that you are hearing at the time. On Vista/Windows 7 this process has changed slightly and isn't normally enabled by default.

Have a look at this explanation on how to enable the disabled sound devices:
http://techblissonline.com/download-save-record-or-capture-streaming-audio-for-free/